# DateTimeOffset Support in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: sql, compact-framework

Does anyone know if the data type "DateTimeOffset" is supported in the .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.  Can you tell us what your usage scenario is and maybe we can suggest a workaround?  My guess is you can create your own class something like this that would probably work:

```
class MyDateTimeOffset
{
    public DateTime UTCTime { get; set; }
    public int BiasInMinutes { get; set; }

    public DateTime AsLocalTime()
    {
        var localBias = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes;

        return UTCTime.AddMinutes(BiasInMinutes - localBias);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to store your DateTime in a Int64 and use the functions **ToFileTimeUtc()** and **DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(long).ToLocalTime()** that exists on both framework versions (.net CF and .net).

```
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now; // our current local DateTime
        long date = localDate.ToFileTimeUtc(); // stores it as an Int64

        DateTime dateUTC = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc( date ); // gets UTC DateTime from the Int64
        DateTime backTolocal = dateUTC.ToLocalTime(); // converts the UTC DateTime to LocalTime
```